# How to define <*> for applicative parser?

Tags: scala, parsing, applicative

Suppose we define parser as a function

```
type Parser[A] = String => List(A, String)
```

The parser takes an input string and yields a sequence of pairs. Each pair consists of the parsing result and unconsumed part of the input

As I understand, we can define the parser as an `applicative` and implement a `seq` parser combinator in terms of `<*>`.

The `seq` combinator is a function, which takes two parsers `p` and `q` as its arguments and returns a new parser, which applies `p` and `q` to the input *sequentially*. For example:

```
val pa  = symbol('a') // parser, which recognizes 'a' as the 1st char in the input
val pb  = symbol('b') // parser, which recognizes 'b' as the 1st char in the input  
val pab = seq(pa, pb) // recognizes "ab"
```

Obviously, we can easily define `flatMap` for the parser and then define `<*>` in terms of that `flatMap`. Can we define `<*>` *differently* and implement `seq` with that `<*>` ?

Comment: Why a _sequence_ of pairs? Can you include e.g. your `symbol` or `flatMap` implementations to show how you're using this?

Comment: I took this parser defintion from  http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/237/1/monparsing.pdf

Comment: I will add the `symbol` and `flatMap` implementations to the question to make it clear.

Comment: @TravisBrown Decided to post a new question rather than update this one. Hope the new question is clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685920/applicative-parser-example-in-scala